# Use cordova-plugin-usagestats in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to use this third-party cordova plugin ([cordova-plugin-usagestats](https://github.com/spec2e/cordova-plugin-usagestats)) in my Ionic 2 project. Of course I added it to my project via `ionic plugin add` and tried it with:

```
declare var usagestats:any;
declare var window:any;
declare var cordova:any;
//
*
//
this.platform.ready().then(
  () => {
console.log(usagestats);
console.log(window.usagestats);
console.log(window.plugin.usagestats);
console.log(cordova.plugin.usagestats)
});
```

Everything is `undefined`. Unfortunately, there is no documentation. Is there anyway to get a solution by looking through the plugin.xml or through the entire source code ?

Thanks in advance